# $ not working for jQuery in new website

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I have been using jQuery for quite a few years now, and after I include the jQuery scripts in whatever site I am working on, I would always use the `$` for jQuery objects.  For example:

```
$('#my_selector').click(function(){...
```

I had built a website a few years ago in Joomla 1.6 with over 200 pages and jQuery used in almost all of them, all with the `$`.  Now I am rebuilding the site in Joomla 3.3.0.  The funny thing is, now sometimes the `$` just doesn't work when identifying jQuery objects, but when I use `jQuery` it works.  For example. the above code example would have to be changed to this:

```
jQuery('#my_selector').click(function(){...
```

And that works.  And the final strangest thing is that on one page, it seems like the `$` works for some of the jQuery but not all.  The error that I see is this one:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Seems like the problem occurs mostly on the functions that run `after load complete` circumstances.  Anyway I am just wondering if people out there know why the `$` would stop working with identifying the jQuery functions and objects.

Thanks!

Comment: did you refer jquery multiple times in the same page?

Comment: This is most probably because of [jQuery.noconflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/), which causes `$` not to be defined.

Comment: is it bcos of some kind of conflict with other libraries

Comment: Are you using any another library along with jQuery?

Comment: I have not used other libraries explicitly for my code, but whatever libraries are loaded for Joomla 3.3.0 are still loaded of course.  And YES I often have to refer to jQuery many times in the page.

Comment: @cbuckley - yes I see that `jquery-noconflict.js` is included in the head of the site...  Would that be messing it up?

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind it's used to stop `$` being defined as jQuery, in order to (potientially) use other libraries that use `$`. giorgio's closures are good, and also look at the jQuery.noconflict() docs for other examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are most probably using a conflicting library, meaning: another script/library that declares (and thus overrides) the variable `$`. Wrap all your code in a closure, and you should be good:

```
(function($) {
    $('#my_selector').doStuff();
})(jQuery)
```

Or, if it needs to be executed after document ready:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#my_selector').doStuff();
});
```

Comment: I have a bunch of functions in the global scope, and inside the functions the do jquery stuff using the $.  Is it possible to create a closure around all those functions?  With the functions still be able to be called from global scope?

Answer (score 1):

Are you or joomla using mootools or any other library with the `$`?

This would mean there is a conflict and the right way to solve it, is by using `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla 3.x is moving progressively to jQuery and replacing all MooTools dependencies along the way.

The default state is to load `jQuery` in `noConflict()` mode, but depending on features used on any given page by extensions (`templates`,`plug-ins`, `components` or `modules`) MooTools may also be loaded.

That means that on some pages, `jQuery` is defined and not `$` and on other pages both are defined, obviously this will result in the issues you are seeing.

Add to that most third-party extensions from the 1.6 era (you have been upgrading to the 2.5.x line along the way right?) just ignored what-ever was going on and loaded whatever they needed (potentially blowing away other libraries) you generally will have to sort out all the conflicts first.

The only guaranteed way to use jQuery is by using the `jQuery` prefix.

You can read about [using JavaScript frameworks with Joomla here](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x%3aJavascript_Frameworks), amongst other things it gives you future proof mechanism built-in to Joomla for loading jQuery.

To load jQuery, use: `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');`

To load the jQuery UI core call: `JHtml::_('jquery.ui');`

As has been mentioned you can wrap your JavaScript in a closure, in fact this is what the core `com_banners` does in `/media/cbanner.js`

```
var jQuery;
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#jform_type').on('change', function (a, params) {
                var v = typeof(params) !== 'object' ? $('#jform_type').val() : params.selected;
                switch (v) {
                case '0':
                    // Image
                    $('#image, #url').show();
                    $('#custom').hide();
                    break;
                case '1':
                    // Custom
                    $('#image, #url').hide();
                    $('#custom').show();
                    break;
                }
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
```